# Is google maps api v3 support multitouch for zooming?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, multi-touch, zooming

I try google maps in default web brouser on my Sony Ericsson Active (android 2.3.4), but I found that multitouch zooming doesn't work.

Is google maps api v3 support multitouch zooming or anybody know scripts for this.

**UPDATE**

I found next information: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch.html:

> On the Android Gingerbread Browser (tested on Nexus One and Nexus S),
>   there is no multi-touch support. This is a known issue
>   (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909)

And this feature implemented in android 4.0 (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11909#c19).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the google maps api v3 supports multitouch. It's possible to see it on a iOS with the Safari. I think the browser is the problem on android devices. It does not send the touch events to the map, because it interprets the touch commands as webpage zoom. So it seems to be currently not possible to use multitouch with google map on androids default browser.